# How to implement a rich text editor using Polymer?

Tags: html, web, tinymce, polymer, web-component

I tried to integrate TinyMCE with Polymer but it doesn't work due to the Shadow DOM.

Also, I tried to follow this instructions from the bellow link, but still doesn't work either.

[How do I wrap tinyMCE inside a polymer element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728265/how-do-i-wrap-tinymce-inside-a-polymer-element)

Comment: Did you find any rich text editor polymer component?

Comment: Looking for one myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use polymer-quill which is based on popular quilljs WYSIWYG editor.

example:

```html
<style is="custom-style">
  polymer-quill.full {
    --polymer-quill-editor-max-height: 300px;
    --polymer-quill-editor-min-height: 100px;
  }
</style>
<h2>Full Toolbar, Show Results, Max Height (300px), Min Height (100px), Save as Deltas, Save every 1 second</h2>
<polymer-quill content='{"ops":[{"insert":"Hello World! - Store as Delta"},{"attributes":{"header":2},"insert":"\n"}]}'
  class='full'
  store-as="delta"
  save-interval="1000"
  toolbar-type="full"
  show-results>
</polymer-quill>
<h2>Standard Toolbar, Hide Results, Default height (100px), Save as HTML, Save every 2 seconds</h2>
<polymer-quill content="<h2>Hello World! - Store as HTML</h2>" store-as="html"></polymer-quill>
```

go to [polymer-quill github](https://github.com/chuckh/polymer-quill) for more info

Comment: Well, I have used Polymer Quill in version Polymer 1.0. However, is it possible for it to work perfectly with Polymer 2.0?

Comment: it'll not work as of now. however developer has plan to update it to polymer 2.0 . no idea when it might be done.

Comment: There is a wrapper of it written for Polymer2. You can find it here. https://github.com/arsnebula/polymer-quill

Comment: I have integrated and it is working fine in production.